# get element text for web service in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

From below  soap response, if I want only the customdata part i.e ABCD1234564754 as the response, which keyword should i use.

${abc} = https://test.com/i?formid=5Z0C&customdata=ABCD1234564754

As of now, I have written below code:

```
Call Soap Method    GetABCURL    ${GetABCURL}
${soap_response}    Get Last Received
Log    ${soap_response}
${GetABCURLResult} =   get element text     ${soap_response}
```

I want ${GetABCURLResult} set to  ABCD1234564754

Comment: with get element text , I am getting all text , I just want the customdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Split String` with separator as `customdata=`

```
${abc}=  Set Variable  https://test.com/i?formid=5Z0C&customdata=ABCD1234564754

${xyz}  Split String  ${abc}  customdata=

${customdata}  Remove String  ${xyz[1]}  </WEB>
Log To Console  ${customdata}
```

index zero will have all unnecessary data, index 1 will have your desired result.

Comment: my URL is in following format

<WEB><WEB>https://test.com/i?formid=5Z0C&customdata=ABCD1234564754</WEB></WEB>

Using split string gives me    ABCD1234564754</WEB></WEB> . I dont want </WEB></WEB>

Comment: Simplest approach will be removing trailing </WEB>
`${customdata}  Remove String  ${xyz}  </WEB>`
It will remove all occurrences of WEB.
There can be single line solution possible but this will be the simplest one.